# Can U.2 be passively converted to M.2?

Tags: ssd, nvme

If I understand correctly, both U.2 as well as M.2 (Key M) connectors output 4x pci-e lanes through the pins. Does that mean a completely passive adapter is possible between the two, or does one of them do something the other doesn't?

Comment: You mean devices like https://www.amazon.com/U-2-M-2-Adapter-Interface-Drive/dp/B073WGN61Y , https://www.newegg.com/p/2WG-00J0-00028?item=9SIAFJV6SF9527 , or https://click.intel.com/u-2-to-m-2-ssd-cable-replacement-u-2-to-m-2-cable-for-pcie-nvme-supporting-intel-solid-state-drives.html ?

Comment: @K7AAY that looks like a Mini-SAS HD (SFF-8613) port https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI and AFAIK SCSI isn't pci-e?

Comment: PCI-e drives can and do connect w/ using Mini-SAS cables. But, back to my first comment; which device are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what key this is but... Will this work? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073W65QX6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_Hsw3DbW42XPDR

Comment: Actually it says m key.

Comment: yep was looking for this I think, thanks Hellreaver :)

Comment: Sorta kinda depends as to what you want it to work with, but most of these are passive adapters.

Comment: I have an oculink connector on my mainboard and a M.2 NVMe SSD. as there don't seem to exist any oculink to M.2 cables, but there is a oculink to U.2 cable, I thoughtt I try going from oculink to U.2 to M.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible with the right hardware to go from U.2 to/from M.2.

Here are some random adapters found on Amazon:

[StarTech.com M.2 to U.2 Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073W65QX6)

[image]

[StarTech.com U.2 to M.2 Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073WGN61Y)

[image]